# Merge in Terraform retrurns only the first object

Tags: terraform

I have such a terraform configuration:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "dsvnet_routable" {
  name                = "VNet1"
  resource_group_name = "MyRG"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "dsvnet_noneroutable" {
  name                = "VNet2"
  resource_group_name = "MyRG"
}
```

I would like to merge the result of these two blocks as following and summrize it  in my output

```
locals {
  virtual_network = merge(data.azurerm_virtual_network.dsvnet_routable,data.azurerm_virtual_network.dsvnet_noneroutable)
}
```

in my output:

```
output "virtual_network_id" {
value = local.virtual_network
}
```

but I only see the result for `data.azurerm_virtual_network.dsvnet_routable`. What should I do to have the both in my output?

Comment: I'm guessing both are returning maps which have the same keys, so merge uses the last one as the result. From the docs: `If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence.`

Comment: Considering the `merge` parameters are the same object structures, then @MarkoE comment is almost certainly the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge

> Merge takes an arbitrary number of maps or objects, and returns a single map or object that contains a merged set of elements from all arguments.
>
> If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence. If the argument types do not match, the resulting type will be an object matching the type structure of the attributes after the merging rules have been applied.

Your problem is best seen with an example:

```hcl
locals {
    foo = {a:1, b:1, x:1}
    bar = {a:2, b:2, y:2}
}

output "merged" {
  value = merge(local.foo, local.bar)
}
```

if we do a `terraform plan` on that code we get:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + merged = {
      + a = 2
      + b = 2
      + x = 1
      + y = 2
    }
```

As you can see it merges the two objects into one

---

If you want to see both you can include them in one list:

```hcl
locals {
    foo = {a:1, b:1, x:1}
    bar = {a:2, b:2, y:2}
    both = [local.foo, local.bar]
}

output "both" {
  value = local.both
}
```

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + both = [
      + {
          + a = 1
          + b = 1
          + x = 1
        },
      + {
          + a = 2
          + b = 2
          + y = 2
        },
    ]
```

---

Another option creating a new object instead of a list:

```hcl
locals {
  foo = { a: 1, b: 1, x: 1 }
  bar = { a: 2, b: 2, y: 2 }
  both = {
    the_foo : local.foo,
    one_bar : local.bar
  }
}

output "both" {
  value = local.both
}
```

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + both = {
      + one_bar = {
          + a = 2
          + b = 2
          + y = 2
        }
      + the_foo = {
          + a = 1
          + b = 1
          + x = 1
        }
    }
```

---

One last option I would suggest is using a `for_each` instead of multiple data in your code, In my opinion it makes it cleaner.

```hcl
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "routables" {
  for_each = toset(["VNet1", "VNet2"])
  name                = each.value
  resource_group_name = "MyRG"
}

output "routables" {
  value = data.azurerm_virtual_network.routables
}
```